# Novel about rescuing the people of a dying planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, religion, space-colonization

Trying to find a book I've read about ten years ago.  It was translated into Russian, the original was (probably) written in English.

It was about a planet in a solar system with a single red giant star. The hero was the strong 'n silent type,  some kind of cosmic tarzan, raised by a group of NH primates which, if i remember, at the time of the story are extint (killed by humans? ) He was sent to the planet as a part of a rescue attempt of the locals (?) by some galactic union. The inhabitants of the planet were refusing to leave the planet, their scripture(s)  (or religious leaders?) forbidding them to do so.
There was a blond woman(a seer?) travelling with the hero, assisting him on his quest. The woman in the end gets sacrificed by the natives to the sun/to bring warmth. There were also some strange races about,  results of a genetic engineering (half human, half cats living underground? Under water?) created in an attempt to adapt to the planet.

Comment: What does _NH_ stand for?

Comment: Oh, sorry. NH = non-human

Answer (score 2):

There are some non-trivial similarities to [Harry Harrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Harrison_(writer))'s *[Planet of the Damned](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?186628)*, (also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Damned)) though if this is the correct answer there were either some changes in translation of you are misremembering parts of the story.

In the Harrison story, the ruling class of the desert planet Dis are threatening their neighboring planet with colbalt bombs and the neighbors are planning to wipe out the Disians before that can happen. The natives are humans who have adapted to the heat in part through establishing symbiotic relationships with some of the native life. They also live in caves for safety and protection against the worst of the heat. There is a female sidekick/love interest, though I can't recall if she has blond hair.

The [full text is available from Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21873) and an audio version is [available from librivox](https://librivox.org/planet-of-the-damned-by-harry-harrison/).

Comment: No, it's not that one. I think the author is much less famous than H. Harrison.